# Should I vote to reopen my edited question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

My very first question on Stack Overflow, 3 years ago, was an absolutely terrible question, and was quite rightly downvoted and closed at the time.

Much later, I started learning how to ask better questions. I started learning about the value of editing. I read the FAQs and Meta, and started to ( I hope ) become a worthwhile and responsible Stack Overflow user (still working on it).

If memory serves I both tried and failed to vote to reopen this question, and to have it deleted - but I may be wrong, I can't find a history of those actions.

Some time ago, I returned to the question and attempted to edit it to make it not suck, and I think I didn't do too badly.

The question in... er question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707202/how-to-get-a-count-of-grouped-rows-in-mysql

So now, having recently earned the ability to vote to close and reopen, I find myself wanting to either reopen it or delete it. It is not the same question that was closed, so could be reopened - but in my opinion it's still pretty basic and is covered in other questions, so could be deleted.

The problem is, I can't figure out how much of this is simply selfish desire to have a bad question removed from my history or un-downvoted, and how much is me wanting to improve the question for Stack Overflow in general. I feel like I don't have enough perspective to tell the right course of action.

So I've opted not to do anything - and instead ask the selfless and knowledgeable folks here what they would do, or what they think I should do in this situation.

Comment: some kind soul has deleted the question, thankyou. I was planning to edit again but got called away to work so didn't finish, either way problem solved :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can't delete it since it has an upvoted answer.

As for reopening it, the question still appears to be too broad as the close reason suggests. But, it would be quite difficult to add research effort to an old question that you think has been asked so many times before while also explaining why they didn't answer your question.

I don't really see much that could be done at this point, but reopening does not sound promising. It would either be closed with the new too broad reason or as a duplicate.

What you can do is learn from your mistakes and ask future questions with clear attempts and research effort.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how this question is still 'too broad'? It seems quite specific and answerable to me at the moment, so I am clearly missing something.

Comment: Sure, you use the phrase "Can anyone show me how to..." without showing any clear attempt or research effort. The question just asks for code instead of asking for *help* with a piece of coding that *is not currently working* and showing any questions that have not helped (and explaining why they didn't help) along with any attempts that you have made so far.

Comment: Another thing you can selflessly do is edit the question to include links to other questions/answers that you now realize are essentially duplicates, so that anyone stumbling onto your old question (still closed) derive as much benefit as possible from the site.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Anonymous. I would not classify those things as making the question 'too broad', but I can understand now why it's still closed. (It's not my question by the way, I was just curious.)

Comment: @tmpearce I think I'll do that, good suggestion.

Comment: @Anonymous thanks for the answer & comments, I think you're right about it being too broad and still not a great question - I'll either try to edit it further to make it better, or atleast include links to duplicates. Thanks for the guidance :)

Comment: @Josien Whoops, sorry about that.